# Differences between firebase, loopback and redux

Tags: node.js, meteor, loopback

I want to develop a web app and later corresponding android/ios apps. So far I have only decided the front end for which I want to use react and react native for mobile.

For the rest of the technology stack I am considering using meteor.js, in which case, correct me if I'm wrong, I wouldn't need another technology.

However I am also looking at alternatives and some things I've read about, are loopback, firebase and redux. I'm pretty new to all of this, so I know that this is probably an apples to oranges comparison, but I'm not really sure, what each of those would do for me and if this would be an either/or situation or if I would combine some of these? Redux sounds like it might also fit into a meteor.js workflow?

So summing it up, it would be great, if somebody could explain to me, how all of those fit together and what kind of combinations would make sense as a technology stack.

Comment: It's a good question. However, stackoverflow is specifically for coding questions so this question doesn't fit into the scope. Please see [Good Topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That being said, you *really* need to craft some code in each of the platforms you mentioned. Without a code sample, there's no way for us to know what would work for your use case. I would suggest crafting a simple To Do list app to see if each platform fits into the scope of your project.

Answer (score 3):

## Firebase:

Firebase works like this: one or more users subscribe to some data because they are interested in the information.

A server keeps track of those subscriptions. As soon as a new subscription happens, some data is sent back as message.

When one client writes some data, the pub/sub server broadcasts this update to all the other active subscriptions.

Everything works as pub/sub so there is no such concept of "querying". You just tell what you are interested in then you receive messages who describes the data.

### Pros

- If your app does run a centralized DB and is updated by a lot of users, it's more than capable of handling the Real-Time data updates between devices.
- Stored in the cloud so readily available everywhere.
- Cross platform API (If you are using this DB with an App).
- They host the data, meaning that if you are storing a lot of data, you don't have to worry about hardware!

### Cons:

- Unless your app runs one centralized database updated by a vast quantity of users, it's a major overkill.
- Storage format is entirely different from that of SQL, (Firebase uses JSON) so you wouldn't be able to migrate that easily.
- Reporting tools won't be anywhere near the ones of standard SQL.
- Cost! Limited to 50 connections and 100MB of storage!
- You don't host the data. Firebase does. Depending on which server you get put on, viewing there up time there seems to be a lot of disruption lately.

## Redux

Redux is an architecture pattern and a library. Its gift to you is the ability to manage your application’s state in a single object. Here's an [article](https://medium.com/@juanguardado/react-redux-and-workflow-624e5f65a68f#.jn5c0tjmi) speaking of that, and an [article](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1385)
speaking of the disadvantages of storing all your state in a single immutable atom.

## Loopback

### Pros

- Very quick RESTful API development
- Convention over configuration
- Built-in models ready to use
- RPC support
- Fully configurable when needed
- Extensive documentation
- Fulltime team working on the project
- Available commercial support

Comment: Tips: StackOverflow use Markdown for formatting, it is really powerful. You can read about it in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I've edited your post to show you how clearer it is with it. Also, you have posted two links, it is a good idea to add a short version of the content, so that if the link dies, your answer still have value.

Comment: One correction in the Firebase section please *so there is no such concept of "querying"* is not accurate. Firebase certainly has querying - it returns a subset of your data as any query would do. The cool thing is that it can either return the data once, or can continue to *observe* data that fits the query and return it accordingly. For example; you want all of your users to be notified if a user selects pizza as their favorite food. Set up a query to observe for fav_food = pizza and anytime a user selects pizza, all users will be notified. It's an incredibly powerful query engine.

Comment: One other fix in the Firebase section. The costs are not accurate. The Spark plan has 100 connections and way more than 500m of storage. That's the 'developer' plan. Then as you add users, move to the Flame plan which is more then 2x the Spark plan and unlimited connections. See [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

Comment: Also, IMO, the first Firebase Con about it being an overkill. Not sure I agree with that. It's free online storage with a well supported and documented cross platform API, along with a hands-on development team and a dynamic community. I wouldn't consider that overkill. It would support a single user accessing data real-time from multiple devices to 10,000 users finding the nearest restaurant with a great wine list. Again though, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I certainly have to look at each of them a bit more and do some tutorials. I'm still not a 100% sure how they would or would not work together. Would it be correct so say the following?:

Comment: (Accidentaly posted the comment above without it being finished, is there a way to delete it?)

Thank you for the answer, I certainly have to look at each of them a bit more and do some tutorials. I'm still not a 100% sure how they would or would not work together. Would it be correct so say the following?:

Firebase and Loopback both provide me with a way to access and store my data in a database, although they do it in a different way, so I would probably choose one or the other.

Redux is more about how I structure my app and I could combine it with Firebase as well as with Loopback.